# Prove uniqueness of solution of ODE : ${ y'=a(x)y }$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a little trouble solving this problem :

I need to show that the only solution of : ${ y'=a(x)y }$ , with ${ y( x_0 )= y_0 }$

are functions of the form : ${ f(x)= \lambda e^{A(x)} }$, with A(x) the antiderivative of $a(x)$.

Should I try to show that the derivative of ${ g(x)=f(x_0+h)f(x_0-h) }$ is equal to $0$, therefore that $g(x)$ is a constant function, therefore that $f(x)$ is either identically zero, or never equal to $0$. And then, show that two functions that are solutions of the differential equation are necessarily equal to each other ?

Or is there another way ? Because I don't see how to prove that $g'(x)=0$ .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
y'(x)=a(x)y(x), \\ y(x_0)=y_0
\end{array}\right. \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\exp\big(-\int_{x_0}^xa(t)\,dt\big)\big(y'(x)-a(x)y(x)\big)=0, \\ y(x_0)=y_0
\end{array}\right. \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
$$
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\Big(y(x)\exp\big(-\int_{x_0}^xa(t)\,dt\big)\Big)'=0, \\ y(x_0)=y_0
\end{array}\right.
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
y(x)\exp\big(-\int_{x_0}^xa(t)\,dt\big)=c, \\ y(x_0)=y_0
\end{array}\right.
$$
for some $c\in\mathbb  R$. Setting $x=x_0$, we obtain
$$
c=y(_0)\exp\big(-\int_{x_0}^{x_0}a(t)\,dt\big)=y(x_0)=y_0.
$$
Thus finally
$$
y(x)=y_0\exp\big(\int_{x_0}^xa(t)\,dt\big).
$$
Note. The procedure above established *uniqueness*, since if $z=z(x)$ is another solution of the IVP, then following the same procedure for $z$ we obtain that
$$
z(x)=y_0\exp\big(\int_{x_0}^xa(t)\,dt\big).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since antiderivatives of $a$ differ by additive constants (locally constant functions if we're pedantic), exponentials thereof differ multiplicatively, so we may as well replace the $\lambda$ with $\pm$. So let's *define* $A(x):=\ln|y|$ and check $A^\prime=a$. Indeed, $(\ln|y|)^\prime=y^\prime/y=a$, as required.